# Devanagaric text processing(NLP) where to start

Tags: nlp, text-processing, devanagari

I am new to Devnagaric NLP, Is there any group or resources that would help me get started with NLP in Devnagaric language(Mostly Nepali language or similar like Hindi).  I want to be able to develop fonts for Devanagaric and also do some font processing application. If anyone (working in this field), could give me some advice then it would be highly appreciable.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

> I am new to Devnagaric NLP, Is there any group or resources that would help me get started with NLP in Devnagaric language(Mostly Nepali language or similar like Hindi)

You can use embeddings given by fasttext [https://fasttext.cc/docs/en/pretrained-vectors.html#content] and use some deep learning RNN models like LSTM for text-classification, sentiment analysis.

You can find some datasets for named entity recoginition here [http://ltrc.iiit.ac.in/ner-ssea-08/index.cgi?topic=5]

For Processing Indian languages, you can refer here [https://github.com/anoopkunchukuttan/indic_nlp_library]

Nltk supports the indian lanugages, for pos tagging and nlp related tasks you can refer here [http://www.nltk.org/_modules/nltk/corpus/reader/indian.html]

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any group or resources that would help me get started with NLP in Devnagaric language?

The [Bhasa Sanchar project](http://www.bhashasanchar.org/about.php) under Madan Puraskar Pustakalaya has developed a Nepali corpus. You may request a Nepali corpus for non-commerical purposes from the contact provided in the link above.

Python's NLTK has the Hindi Language corpus. You may import it using

```
from nltk.corpus import indian
```

For gaining insight to Devnagari based NLP, I suggest you go through research papers.Nepali being an under-resourced language;much work yet to be done, and it might be difficult to get contents for the same.

You should probably look into language detection,text classification,sentiment analysis among others (preferably based on POS tagging library from the corpus) for grasping the basics.

**For the second part of the question**

I am pretty sure font development doesn't come under the domain of Natural Language Processing. Did you mean something else?